# Error:Timeout waiting to lock buildscript class cache for build file when change minSdkVersion

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I try to change `minSdkVersion` in `build.gradle` (Module: app) in `Android Studio` and get next error:

```
Error:Timeout waiting to lock buildscript class cache for build file 'E:\pathtoproject\app\build.gradle' (C:\Users\Administrator\.gradle\caches\2.2.1\scripts\build_f00bwdji3qxl7urq5chsbakgv\ProjectScript\buildscript). It is currently in use by another Gradle instance.
Owner PID: unknown
Our PID: 4592
Owner Operation: unknown
Our operation: Initialize cache
Lock file: C:\Users\Administrator\.gradle\caches\2.2.1\scripts\build_f00bwdji3qxl7urq5chsbakgv\ProjectScript\buildscript\cache.properties.lock
```

**What is it error? How to change `minSdkVersion` ?**

Comment: I got same error after running proguard, I restarted android studio and it worked for me then

Comment: i restarted android studio, it didn't work. restarted the laptop and it worked

Answer (score 102):

This sounds like it's related to https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2795.

The easiest way to solve this will be to delete everything under `C:\Users\Administrator\.gradle\caches`. There is a `cache.properties.lock` that is holding a global lock which is preventing you from running your script.

For Mac OSX the folder is located in `~/.gradle/caches`. The Android Studio should show the proper path to the file which is causing the lock anyway.

Comment: what is the path for Mac osx ?

Comment: It should be in your home directory. `~/.gradle/caches`

Comment: Had 65k files in that dir. Thumbs up

Comment: I just deleted that one file. no point deleting the cache. i guess its there so don't have to download from the inter webs every time. a good idea if u ask me.

Comment: Agreed, there's no need to delete the entire cache. When I ran into this issue before there were multiple lock files and rather than tracking them down one by one I just got rid of the whole directory to save time.

Comment: I had to delete/move the whole caches directory.

Comment: Took half an hour just to make a backup copy all the folder/files in there first. Then some hidden process prevented the deleting of the lock files, had to restart the laptop. Another weird android error to research and fix that cost an afternoon.

Comment: fck, it was 4.3 GB

Comment: proceed with caution since you may need to download a whole bunch of files on the next build

Comment: how to remove? After leaving Android Studio, FileExplorer shows that that directory has locked items. I have to reboot! How to release them without reboot??

Answer (score 26):

> File > Invalidate cache / restart

works for me!!!

[image]

Comment: Works without invalidate cache, just a simple restart is good enough.

Comment: This error can happen on the command-line, not just Android Studio.

Comment: the above fixes work for cmd but intelliJ or Android Studio create new lock files. Even when deleting the cache via shell I just get the error referencing a different lock file

Answer (score 24):

I have got the same issue:

[image]

To resolve this issue, kill the process which retain the journal with `kill -9` command

Log explain perfectly which process is involved in your issue, so you can retrieve the PID or the file path concerned

In this example, the command will be:

`kill -9 9739`

Note: `9739` is Owner PID of above screenshot: `Owner PID: 9739`

Comment: Don't forget sudo :)

Comment: thanks in my case the PIC number was different. thats it. thanks a lot. stuck on this for so long. but now if i am running two android studio window i have to kill everytime i need to run other project. any permanent solution for this? do let know.

Comment: This was the only answer in this thread that worked for me in 2022

Comment: for me this keep recurring which means I have to kill the process hogging the lock every time. I still cannot find the root cause yet. I only have one project open thru intellij but it seems like intellij's indexing/gradle build is not exiting properly for me

Answer (score 11):

The lock file is there because some other gradle process (usually the daemon) is using the cache. You could stop all gradle processes to release the lock

```
gradle --stop
```

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:stopping_an_existing_daemon

Answer (score 9):

for me, it solved the problem by killing the PID

- **Windows**  taskkill /F /PID pid_number
- **Linux**  kill -9 pid_number

Answer (score 5):

1.Check whether multiple instance of **java.exe** running then find out why they are running in my case i have opened command prompt it need java instance.
open task manager and end task of **cmd.exe**
If you don't want it to further happen remove path from environment variables and use embedded android studio JDK.

2.Delete lock file in /.gradle/cache
goto task manager and close all instance of java.exe
In android studio click on file invalidate caches/restart

Answer (score 4):

Close android studio and delete anything in cache

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me.

## kill all instances of the gradle process.

`ps -ef | grep gradle`

## delete the 'Lock file'

`rm C:\Users\Administrator\.gradle\caches\2.2.1\scripts\build_f00bwdji3qxl7urq5chsbakgv\ProjectScript\buildscript\cache.properties.lock`

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me:

```
projectPath=[yourProjectPath]
find $projectPath/.gradle -name '*.lock' -delete
```

You can also remove them one by one:

```
gradleVersion=[yourProjectGradleVersion]
projectPath=[yourProjectPath]
rm -f $projectPath/.gradle/$gradleVersion/taskHistory/taskHistory.lock $projectPath/.gradle/$gradleVersion/fileHashes/fileHashes.lock $projectPath/.gradle/$gradleVersion/fileContent/fileContent.lock $projectPath/.gradle/$gradleVersion/javaCompile/javaCompile.lock $projectPath/.gradle/buildOutputCleanup/buildOutputCleanup.lock
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete .gradle folder from / and resync gradle from project.

Answer (score 0):

Your **build.gradle** file likely contains multiple statements of 
`minSdkVersion`.  Possibly in `defaultConfig{}` block and `productFlavors{}` block.  Make sure you are only declaring minSdkVersion **once** in the build file.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it was notable  to delete filehash.lock file and it will throw an error unable to delete file. So do the following steps

For Windows machine:

Open Task Manager(Ctrl-Alt-Delete and check Process)

-> If you run two instance of android studio, Close One (End Task)

-> Then close OpenJDK Platform Binary

-> Gradle sync now on AndroidStudio and it will work now

Answer (score 0):

For me the only thing that worked was deleting these things inside android folder:

- {appname}.iml
- .idead/
- .gradle/buildOutputCleanup/

Posting this for myself 2 weeks from now

Answer (score 0):

For A novice like me, who encountered the situation for the first time and was not able to delete the .lock file or the .gradle folder,

In windows 10 or others, restart the pc using safe mode,(windows key + R ---> msconfig ----> select boot, boot in safe mode----> restart) then delete the files, (this should delete the files and folder)

then in normal mode, restart android studio and sync gradle to download the appropriate version (hopefully the project should work now)

Answer (score 0):

```
"Lock file: C:\Users\Administrator\.gradle\caches\2.2.1\scripts\build_f00bwdji3qxl7urq5chsbakgv\ProjectScript\buildscript\cache.properties.lock"
```

You should delete the file in this extension. Then you will see that the problem is fixed. I lived the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the folder helped me C:\Users*username*.gradle\caches\journal-1.

I unlocked the folder to delete and did Invalidate cache and restart.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a Mac:

I generated this error and a bunch of related errors that lead to this question when you search them. Default 'Hello World' app builds for IOS right off the bat. Android build fails with a bunch of .lock timeouts with errors like this:

> Timeout waiting to lock Build Output Cleanup Cache (Path/flutter_application_1/android/.gradle/buildOutputCleanup). It is currently in use by this Gradle process.Owner Operation: unknown

If you delete all the locks, eventually you will get these errors:

Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
Execution failed for task ':app:cleanMergeDebugAssets'

After wasting a couple of days on tracking down the solution to these errors, I stumbled upon a somewhat related Gradle thread.

Solution: Because my external SSD is much larger than my internal drive, I was using the external drive for development programs. It was formatted as ExFAT. Used it for many months and only ran into a problem when I tried to build an Android app. **Format to Mac OS Extended or APFS.** All errors went away and builds succeeded for Android and IOS on my first try after reformatting.

Answer (score -1):

Issue: If you open two Android Studios, and two of them are using Camera Services to capture image then we you face this issue.

Solution: Close One Android Studio.