# Android studio build gradle sync failed

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-maps-v2

I am trying to add google play service to my project but it gives me error when I try to edit build (Gradle).

[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31784132/errortimeout-waiting-to-lock-buildscript-class-cache-for-build-file-when-change

Comment: You're missing `'` at the end of line `compile....`

Comment: Please include error message and script in post, not just a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your configuration there some issues.

- You are using **the wrong** `build.gradle` file.
  It is your **top-level** file.
  You should add this line in your `app/build.gradle`
- There is a typo. You are missing the `'` at the end of the line compile.
- Use an **updated version**.

For example use:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
        ...

        dependencies {
            compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
        }
```

Finally refer this [official doc](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) for more info.

> In versions of Google Play services prior to 6.5, you had to compile the entire package of APIs into your app. In some cases, doing so made it more difficult to keep the number of methods in your app (including framework APIs, library methods, and your own code) under the 65,536 limit.
>
> For example if you need to make only your app aware of location updates add
>     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.1.0' only in gradle or if you need only map choose compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.1.0'.

Comment: I had these do i have to remove them and keep only play service?
dependencies 
{compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
}

Comment: @Saleh923 Refer this answer. There are 2 build.gradle file in your project. You are using the wrong file to add the dependencies.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23241681/why-are-there-two-build-gradle-files-in-an-android-studio-project/23241888#23241888

Answer (score 1):

Please replace

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.36`

with

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.36'`

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try is Right Click on **app** open **module settings** on Dependencies Tab click **'+'** icon and add there **'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'** and click search icon and add that dependency,

Answer (score 0):

So i don't want to elaborate what you had done wrong as my colleagues figured it out.I like to say, while playing with **Google Play Service**

> Selectively compile APIs into your executable

*In versions of Google Play services prior to 6.5, you had to compile the entire package of APIs into your app. In some cases, doing so made it more difficult to keep the number of methods in your app (including framework APIs, library methods, and your own code) under the 65,536 limit.*

> For example if you need to make only your app aware of location
>   updates add   ***compile
>   'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.1.0***' only in gradle
>   or if you need only map choose ***compile
>   'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.1.0'***.

*Thank you.*

[Visit](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) for more.