# OneDrive interfering with Gradle syncing project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, onedrive

I've cloned a repo to my OneDrive and tried opening the project in Android Studio.  Gradle will get partway through syncing the project and throws an error:

```
Gradle 'projectname' project refresh failed
Error:Timeout waiting to lock Build Output Cleanup Cache (O:\path\to\project\.gradle\buildOutputCleanup). It is currently in use by another Gradle instance.
Owner PID: unknown
Our PID: 8928
Owner Operation: unknown
Our operation: 
Lock file: O:\path\to\project\.gradle\buildOutputCleanup\cache.properties.lock
```

I've found [Error:Timeout waiting to lock buildscript class cache for build file when change minSdkVersion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31784132/errortimeout-waiting-to-lock-buildscript-class-cache-for-build-file-when-change) and tried deleting the `cache.properties.lock` file, and even tried deleting the `buildOutputCleanup` folder, but I continue to get the error when Gradle syncs.  I tried testing cloning the same repo to my C:, and Gradle synced the project without any problem.

We have OneDrive set up to look like a network share, and I know it has to sync the files I load locally up into the cloud but it seems like that's interfering with Gradle for some reason.  Any idea why this is happening?