# Failed build Project after change directory to external storage; Timeout waiting to lock Java compile cache (/.gradle/7.0.2/javaCompile)

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I have an issue when building project after created a new project in different volumes in Mac Os.

This what error said :

```
Could not create service of type DefaultGeneralCompileCaches using GradleScopeCompileServices.createGeneralCompileCaches().
   > Timeout waiting to lock Java compile cache (/Volumes/SDMICRO/ANDROID/AwPlayerTes/.gradle/7.0.2/javaCompile). It is currently in use by another Gradle instance.
     Owner PID: unknown
     Our PID: 2394
     Owner Operation: unknown
     Our operation: 
     Lock file: /Volumes/SDMICRO/ANDROID/AwPlayerTes/.gradle/7.0.2/javaCompile/javaCompile.lock
```

Actually this is not my true directory in development project. But i have no choices because of run out of space. But this project are failure build. I have tried some solution like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31784132/errortimeout-waiting-to-lock-buildscript-class-cache-for-build-file-when-change). But none of them are works, FYI i use Mac and Android Studio Archtic Fox.

Please someone help me

Answer (score 0):

please try to delete the Lock file, and then rebuild the project.
I encoutered the same problem and already solved it.

Comment: i have tried to delete `checksum.lock` and can not rebuild. Then i try invalidated cache and restart but no still had same issue